# R.layout.main & R.id.gridview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I keep getting the above errors despite "import android.R;" or "import my.package.name.R"

I'm following the Android tutorial on Grid View here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

My Code:

```
package com.examp.yoGridView;


import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class CreateActivityBoxChecked extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); //<<<<< ECLIPSE ERROR HERE

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview); //<<<<< ECLIPSE ERROR HERE
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateActivityBoxChecked.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've also used "CTRL + SHIFT + O" to organize any missing imports, yet no luck. Cleaning made no difference either.

Your suggestions?

Error messages displayed on the Eclipse console:

```
Errors (2 items)
 R.id.gridview cannot be resolved
 R.layout.main cannot be resolved
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Just cleaned it, no difference!

Comment: You should not have to import R at all.  You definitely don't want to import android.R.   What is under your project/gen directory?   Is there additional info in the Problems view (Window|Show View|Problems)?

Comment: It is a known bug. You did not do it. The IDE did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this problem a lot in my class.  If you remove "import android.R", your program should work.  The problem is that Eclipse is looking for Android.R.layout.main instead of com.example.yoGridView.R.layout.main.

Comment: should i have "import com.example.yoGridView.R" instead? i saw these suggestions elsewhere

Comment: well, i just took you advice (didn't bother including "import com.example.yoGridView.R") and it worked! It's strange bc at first i didn't have "import android.R" yet had similar problems. Thanks again

Comment: I'm so glad it worked.  You don't need to import com.example.yoGridView.R because you automatically have access to everything in the current package, so referencing R is equivalent to referencing com.example.yoGridView.R unless you explicitly import a different R package.

Comment: +1 eclipse seems to add the android.r namespace if you do a ctrl+shift +o sometimes. At any rate, this is confusing ...this works and is a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml has errors R.java is not generated.